# Example for proper inclusion in Lorentz space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

The details about Lorentz space are given in [Wikipedia page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space%23Decreasing_rearrangements&ved=2ahUKEwihiq7UlK79AhVkUnwKHZ8vAdcQ0gIoAXoECDQQAg&usg=AOvVaw0LiqTIdto30alovhipvvu7). It is easy to prove that $L^{p,q}$ is contained in $L^{p,r}$ whenever $q<r$. I'm trying to construct an example which shows that the inclusion is proper. I tried examples like $f=\frac{1}{x^{1/p}}\chi_{(0,1)}$. But they are not working. Can I get a precise example for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try $f=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-q}2^{-j/p}\chi_{(0,2^{-j})}$, or equivalently $f(x)=x^{-1/p}|\log x|^{-q}\chi_{(0,\frac12)}$.